# What would be a pattern matching only numbers that are not real?

Tags: pattern-matching

I wanted to delete all complex numbers out of a list, and I tried the following, but it didn't work. Suggestions?

```
Im[x] != 0
```

Comment: More details: provide a sample list, and provide the code that you tried (not just the logical expression, e.g. did you use `DeleteCases`, `Select`, or...). This seems to work: `Select[{1, 2 + I, 3., Sqrt[2] + 0. I}, Im[#] != 0 &]`.

Comment: I used deletecases on a flattened table. DeleteDuplicates worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = {5,  5 + 7 I, 4.9, \[Pi], 8 - 7.4 I};

Select[mylist, # \[Element] Reals &]
```

$\{5,4.9,\pi \}$

and....

```
Select[mylist, Im[#] != 0 &]
```

$\{5+7 i,8.\, -7.4 i\}$

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pattern that matches only numbers that are not real (according to your title), use `Except[_Real, _?NumberQ]`:

```
list = {I, 1, 2.2, 3 + 4 I, a, "hello", 3.14, E^(I Pi), Pi};
Cases[list, Except[_Real, _?NumberQ]]

(* {I, 1, 3 + 4 I, -1} *)
```

But keep in mind that this is matching on the heads of expressions, so something like `1` or `Pi` are not considered real because their heads are `Integer` and `Symbol`, respectively.

On the other hand, if you just want to match complex numbers like the text of your post suggests, use `_Complex`:

```
DeleteCases[list, _Complex]

(* {1, 2.2, a, "hello", 3.14, -1, Pi} *)
```